# One syllable words with many vowel sounds

Tags: english, language, open-ended

I'm not entirely sure how to word this, but what is the largest set of one syllable words you can find in which every phonetic sound is the same except the vowel? For example, 'arc', 'orc', and 'irk' are a 3 word set in which each word is pronounced _rk with the _ replaced by ä, ô, and ə, respectively. Vowel combinations and diphthongs are allowed, but not adding more vowels in a different place is not. For example, 'orca' does not fit into the above set and neither does 'park'.

> I came up with a set containing at least four or five words, but I'm hoping you all can find more

Words are considered valid if they are contained in the OED. Acronyms do not count.

I realize that I wasn't quite clear earlier about what constitutes a valid answer. What we're really looking for here is a set of words whose phonetic spellings are the same except for their phonetic vowel or vowels. So in my earlier example of cute, cut, kite, etc. 'cute' should probably be disqualified because it is pronounced 'kjut' where j is considered a phonetic consonant according to the [OED list of phonetic letters](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/key-to-pronunciation).

Also, words like 'bird' are acceptable in the same list as 'bed' if you specify that they are being pronounced 'bəːd' (the English way) not 'bərd'(the American way) I wasn't going to include those, but I changed my mind, sorry @RosieF, you were right.

Homophones only count as one word, so 'cote' and 'coat' are only one word since they are both pronounced 'kəʊt'.

If you feel like two words are pronounced differently, but I or someone else disagrees with you, see if you can find two separate phonetic spellings to justify your point.

Comment: You might want to define what is considered a valid "word".  e.g. Is it anything found on dictionary.com?  Are proper nouns allowed?  Acronyms? Abbreviations?  Prefixes/Suffixes?

Comment: you could use a tool like [RhymeZone](http://www.rhymezone.com/help/) *([example for ark](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=ark&typeofrhyme=perfect&org1=syl&org2=l))* to get such lists

Comment: It would help if you could further define what is acceptable.  Are homophones (e.g. **so** / **sew**) considered separate words?  Are words containing an unpronounced **R** in certain dialects (e.g. **bard**) considered to have the same consonant phonemes as those without (e.g. **bad**)?  Are proper nouns acceptable (e.g. **Tet**, **Kate**)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Comment: @bobble I feel like this one might be sufficiently bounded: there's only finitely many one-syllable words. (What exactly counts as a word, and what pronunciation is used, are issues here, but not open-endedness issues.)

Answer (score 11):

> bead, bid, bed, bad, baaed (what the sheep did), bard, bod, bud (both Northern and Southern English pronunciations), booed, bird, bayed, buoyed, bored, board, bawd, baud (if pronounced with an accurate French vowel as in "eau", rather than an English one as in "owe"), bode, bowed (made a bowing gesture), bide, beard, bared.

That is $21$

Some of these will sound the same in some accents, but in others they will sound different.

Comment: while buoyed is acceptable, bard, bored, board, bird, and bared are not, because of the extra consonant sound. An R is not a vowel!

Comment: @MMAdams In most British English variants, the "r" sound is not pronounced.

Comment: @MMAdams: anyway, this is at least 12: bad, bid, bed, bud, bead, booed, bode, bayed, bawd, baaed, bide, bowed.

Answer (score 5):

**A (now less) sweet set**
these should comply with the newly provided rules:

> ```
>  IPA    oxford  word   (notes: url)
> /sæt/   /sat/   sat
> /sɛt/   /sɛt/   set
> /sɪt/   /sɪt/   sit
> /sɒt/   /sɒt/   sot
> /sɑt/   /sɑːt/  sot    (british, old-fashioned:  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sot)
> /seɪt/  /seɪt/  sate
> /sit/   /siːt/  seat
> /saɪt/  /sʌɪt/  site
> /sut/   /suːt/  suit
> /sɔt/   /sɔːt/  sought
> /sʊt/   /sʊt/   soot
> /sət/   /səːt/  cert   (british: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cert)
> /sɜt/   /sɜːt/  cert   (british: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cert)
> ```

for a total of $\large13$ with no homophones

Comment: Are *sweat, swat, suet, suite* pronounced as monosyllables with diphthongs in any accent?

Comment: Sweat and suite are (I pronounce both as such). I pronounce suet as two syllables and swat might not count for the added 'w'

Comment: removed sweat, swat and suite as they use IPA w which is a consonant, and suet as it is considered two syllables.  removed the homophones.  added British pronunciations of a couple of words containing "r", as they're permissible provided the British pronunciations aren't homophones of other words.

Answer (score 4):

As a start, how about

> **pat**, **pet**, **pit**, **pot**, **put**, **peat**, **pate**, **putt**

There may be more as well; that was just off the top of my head.

Additions from others:

> - **pout** (MMAdams)

Count so far:  $\large9$

Comment: what about "pout"?

Comment: would you count 'poot' ?

Comment: "part", "pert" and "port", if we're speaking British English and not pronouncing the 'r'.

Answer (score 4):

After the rule clarification I'm down to $\large13$ or $\large16$:

13 definites:

- [\ˈpan\ - pan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pan)
- [\ˈpen\ - pen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pen)
- [\ˈpin\ - pin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pin)
- [\ (¦)pän, (¦)pən\ - 'pon](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pon)
- [\ˈpən\ - pun](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pun)
- [\ˈpān\ - pain](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pain), [pane](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pain)
- [\ˈpēn\ - peen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peen), [pein](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pein)
- [\ˈpōn\ - pone](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pone), [pwn](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/pwned.html)
- [(pôn) - pawn](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pawn)
- [\ˈpīn\ - pine](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pine)
- [/pɑːn/ - paan](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paan)
- [(po͞on) - poon](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poon)
- [(pɜːn) - pern](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pern)

3 more that are actually two syllables (but maybe still qualify?):

- [\ˈpē-ˌän, -ən; pā-ˈōn; ˈpyün\ - peon](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peon) (3rd and 4th are unique)
- [\ˈpē-ən, -ˌän\ - paeon](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paeon) (2nd is unique, when picking 34d or 4th above)
- [\ˈpē-ən\ - paean](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paean) (unique when potential homophones above use alternatives)

I've had to discard the rest:

I've not counted these as I find a pronunciation for these from a reputable source without the 'r':

- [\ˈpȯrn\ - porn](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/porn)
- [\ˈpərn, ˈpirn\ pirn](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pirn)

Not sure how this one is pronounced!

- [? - pien](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pien%20check)

Comment: note, all sets of homophones now count as just one entry, which disqualifies several of your words.

Comment: puzzle title says "One syllable words" so I'm pretty sure two syllable words are out. :)   i dropped mine from my answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a set of 11

> mat met mit motte mutt mate meet might (or mite) mote (or moat) mute moot

Answer (score 3):

16

> tan, ten, tin, ton, tun
>  ta'en, tain, taine
>  teen,
>  tine
>  tonne, toon, town
>  tuan, tune
>  tyne

Comment: note, all sets of homophones now count as just one entry, which disqualifies some of your words.

Answer (score 2):

Another set:

> Big, bog, bug, bag, beg, biog

There are probably more, got $6$ so far...

Comment: **brig** and **brag** don't count; they are adding another consonant sound.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain aaahh didn't read the question properly :(

Comment: Maybe it's regional, but biog would be two syllables for me.

Answer (score 2):

> **tat**, **tit**, **tot**/**taut**/**taught**, **tut**, **teat**, **tight**, **tote**, **toot**, **tout**

Not sure if homophones count as separate words.  These also might not be homophones depending on where you live.  (I am Canadian.  In the UK, I think **taught/tote** would be homophones.)

This is either $\large9$ or $\large11$.

Comment: tet (Vietnamese New Year), tart, tate (a small portion or a pinch).

Comment: @RosieF **tart** adds an extra consonant sound.  The other two are proper nouns; not sure if they're allowed.

Comment: For some speakers, perhaps, but not for all! And taught/tote are homophones only for a minority of speakers: Wikipedia says "The THOUGHT–GOAT merger is a merger of the English vowels /ɔː/ and /oʊ/ that occurs in many female speakers of Geordie.[24] It has also been reported as a possibility in some Northern Welsh accents." ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_low_back_vowels#THOUGHT.E2.80.93GOAT_merger )

Comment: @RosieF I think what we've determined is that this puzzle can have different solutions depending on one's regional accent.  Perhaps there are places where **tot/taut/taught/tote** have four distinct pronunciations...

Answer (score 2):

Set of $8$

> So, saw, see, sea, sew, say, sigh, sow....

Answer (score 2):

10 (so far)

> nat, 
>  net, neat,
>  nit, nite, night 
>  not, note, nowt
>  nut

Answer (score 1):

@GentlePurpleRain already has a better answer than my original one, which is

> cut, cat, kite, and cot.

Additions from others

> kit, cote, coot (GentlePurpleRain)

Total Count: 8

Comment: You could add **kit**, **cote**, **coot**...

Comment: Caught, cart. Yes, R isn't a vowel, but so what? neither are G or H.
Not sure if "cute" qualifies -- does the y-sound disqualify it? (And if in some accent there is no y-sound, it is a homophone of coot anyway.)

Comment: @rosieF 'caught' and 'cot' are the same, which is why I didn't include 'coat' either, it is a homophone of 'cote' and 'cart' has a pronounced r. I'm sorry, but I'm american and I am disallowing Rs because to me that makes no sense.

Comment: @MMAdams: "caught" and "cot" are not the same for many English speakers.

Comment: @sumelic In fact, there is something in linguistics called the **cot/caught merger** that classifies speakers based on whether they pronounce these two words the same or differently.

Answer (score 1):

Following the new rules, I think I can get $19$

> a (/æ/ and /ˈeɪ/) 
>  ah (/ɑː/) 
>  aargh (/ˈä/) 
>  awe (/ɔː/) 
>  e (/iː/) 
>  ear (in some accents, /ɪəː/) 
>  err (/əː/) 
>  ew (/ˈɪəuː/ or /ˈiːuː/)  
>  I (/aɪ/) 
>  oar (/ɔəː/) 
> o' (/ə/) 
>  oh (/oʊ/) 
>  oi (/ɔɪ/) 
>  ooh (/uː/) 
>  ow (/aʊ/) 
>  ugh (/ʊh/ and /ʌh/)